# Send Notification To Selected Users in android app

Tags: android, mysql

I don't know about notification side in android applications.I want to send notification to selected users(we can select users using email or username or user id).I use MySQL database. Give me instructions to build app for sending notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you register your app in firebase and save fire base server key in your back end then ant the time of login you take Firebase token id from user (android user with it's email id or user id) the use that fire base token of user and fire base server key you can send push notification from back end for particular user. Take reference by given link.

[Firebase push notification](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/)

Comment: Divyanshu Sonwani thanks for your advice.its grate.but i have one problem.in this videos that send  notification to only one user.how i send to two or more selected users

Comment: add all user in a list with details and the send to google firebase one by on by using loop